# Check if timeout command was successful

Tags: bash, timeout

I am trying to run a command in a bash file and put the output of command in a variable. But the command must NOT take longer than 2 seconds. I use the command:

```
timeout -k 2 2 ls /var/log/;
```

And there is no problem. The command either list the contents of log directory or kills the command in case it took more than two seconds. But when I try to put the output in a variable the commands hangs and doesn't reply or get killed! I use like this:

```
result=$(timeout -k 2 2 ls /var/log/);
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Why would you want to store it in a variable? To store the output of it? I don't see a use where you would need stdout of timeout command

Comment: I want to check weather the result is the contents of the directory or the command has been killed because of the timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `timeout` command will exit with status 124 if it had to kill the process; see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout). So you may try something like:

```
timeout -k 2 2 ls /var/log/ >directory.txt
if [ $? -eq 124 ]
then
  echo "Timeout exceeded!"
else
  cat directory.txt
fi
```